# Spring Cloud Config | Git Based | Not working on windows machine

Tags: spring-cloud

I am trying to workout a Spring Cloud config server based on a simple [Github repository](https://github.com/ksambhav/optosoft-cloud-config).

Hitting the URL on my browser 
**http://localhost:{configServerPort}/{appName}/default** gives excpected result on a linux machine buts fails on windows machine.

After debugging a lottle I could track down the problem in `org.springframework.cloud.config.server.NativeEnvironmentRepository`'s method `Environment clean(Environment value)`.

The inner for loop matches two file paths (around line no. 153) to set the "matches" flag.

In my case the two file paths that gets compared are:-

```
C:\Users\SAMBHA~1.JAI\AppData\Local\Temp\config-repo-7240902103378698827\crm.yml
```

and

```
C:/Users/SAMBHA~1.JAI/AppData/Local/Temp/config-repo-7240902103378698827/
```

(The Git checkout happens in the temp folder)

The `startsWith` check fails because of forward and backward slashes and thus I get incorrect results in the final Environment object.

How can I get it working on all machines independent of OS?

My config:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class OptoSoftCloudConfigApplication {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OptoSoftCloudConfigApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

bootstrap.yml:-

```
spring:
 application:
  name: config-server
---
server:
 port: 8989
---
spring:
 cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/ksambhav/optosoft-cloud-config
```

Spring Cloud version used: 1.0.1.RELEASE

Comment: you should probably log an issue, looks like a bug

Comment: @spencergibb - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/164

Comment: UPDATE: This will be fixed in version 1.0.2. - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/commit/641d5b40e861e5750393a6f57c26d8124c214083